# Cambiar la contraseña root en mysql 8 en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Tengo Ubuntu 20.04 en mi portátil de trabajo.

Después de instalar mysql 8 (he instalado el cliente y el servidor) no puedo conectarme desde consola con el usuario root, ni sin contraseña ni con contraseña. El mysql está recién instalado.

```
$ mysql --user=root -p
```

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Cómo intentas conectarte? QUé error encuentras? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y hazla más específica.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Comparto la solución que encontré:

**1. Levantamos mysqld en modo seguro (mysqld_safe):**

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking &
```

**3. Ahora podemos entrar en mysql sin contraseña:**

```
$ mysql
mysql>
```

**4. Cambiamos el plugin de autenticación y la password del usuario root:**

```
mysql> update mysql.user set authentication_string = concat('*', upper(sha1(unhex(sha1('password'))))), plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where user = 'root';
```

**5. Salimos de mysql y paramos el servidor mysqld en modo seguro:**

```
mysql> exit
$ mysqladmin --user=root -p shutdown
```

**6. Levantamos el servidor normal de mysql y probamos la nueva contraseña:**

```
$ sudo service mysql start
$ mysql --user=root -p
```